# PHP when is it safe to delete a file after upload via cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following to upload files in a loop to a remote service.
Due to low disk space on my server, I need to delete the files after successful upload. When/where (in my code) is it safe to use unlink() on the uploaded file making sure that I'm not deleting it before it's managed to upload to the remote server?

In the following snippet, $filename is the name of the local file I'm uploading and $f is my logfile.

```
 $postfields = array('file' => '@'.$filename, 'username'=>'XXX','password'=>'YYY');

    $retries_limit = 0;

    $ch = curl_init("http://urlofservice.com/request/add");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); 
    $post_result = curl_exec($ch);

    while((curl_errno($ch) > 0 or $retries_limit == 0) and $retries_limit < 10){
        $retries_limit++;

        if(curl_errno($ch)) {

            fwrite($f,"cURL execution failed for ".$filename." with error ".curl_errno($ch).": " . curl_error($ch) ."#\r\n");       

            $secs = 120;
            sleep($secs);
            fwrite($f,"Sleeped for ".$secs." secs and attempting retry # ".$retries_limit." for ".$filename." #\r\n");  

        }   else {

            fwrite($f,"HTTP POST Request for ".$filename." made successfully #" ."\r\n");

        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Note that you're never actually retrying the upload...!? You need to put the `curl_exec` somewhere inside that loop for an actual retry...

Comment: Have a look to this http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php. You should check the md5 file hash before and after. If resulte is same, you can delete the file safely

Comment: @deceze: Good point, skipped my attention, thanks.

Comment: @ceadreak: How do you mean? A little more info on the concept, please?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you No but you can achieve your goal like this way add some authentication on your server and use the authentication to login in your server. Check out below code as sample

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials goes here
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            // Only for https server or comment it if not 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $result= curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE". Does it delete the local file that was just uploaded?

Comment: I thought you may have used DELETE curl request on remote server.